# Did they have witches in Oz before Dorothy's era?

Tags: the-wizard-of-oz

When Dorothy arrived to Oz, she found out that the country was divided into 4 sectors, with a witch (2 good 2 bad) living in each sector and (presumably) ruling it.

Was that always the case or were those 4 witches a unique happenstance that did not happen before Glinda and co?

Canon answers only please (E.g. sourced from Baum's books/notes/statements, not other later authors' work).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_of_Oz#Prehistory) has a very detailed and (IMO) well written section on the history of Oz. It seems that there are a lot of inconsistencies provided by Baum himself. In general however, the answer to your question is no, there were not *always* 4 witches. From *The Tin Woodman of Oz*:

> ***Oz was not always a fairyland**, I am told. Once **it was much like other lands**, except it was shut in by a dreadful desert of sandy wastes that lay all around it, thus preventing its people from all contact with the rest of the world. Seeing this isolation, the fairy band of **Queen Lurline**, passing over Oz while on a journey, **enchanted the country and so made it a Fairyland**. And Queen Lurline left one of her fairies to rule this enchanted Land of Oz, and then passed on and forgot all about it.*

The Wikipedia goes on to state:

> Thenceforward, no one in Oz would ever age, get sick, or die. After becoming a fairyland, Oz harbored **many Witches**, Magicians and Sorcerers until the time when Ozma made magic illegal without a permit.

Though it also shows how "no one would ever age, get sick, or die" is inconsistent with what we see in Oz.